# how to generate pdf file with bangla language in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using  `m_pdf` its working for English language but not working Bangla  language . I already load `m_pdf` library

Please help any one

**This is my controller code:**

```
public function download_pdf(){
    $sess_info = $this->session->userdata('loggin_user');
    $user_name = $sess_info->user_name;
    $profile_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = [];
    //load the view and saved it into $html variable
    $data['get_profile']=$this->Dashboard_model->get_profile($profile_id);
    $html=$this->load->view('users/profile_pdf', $data, true);
    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = $user_name.".pdf";
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");   
}
```

[image: when get bangla language then show this]

Answer (score 0):

Set UTF-8 encoding before putting any data in the PDF

```
$this->m_pdf->pdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$this->m_pdf->pdf->charset_in = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: Then try encoding the HTML directly `$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');` before `WriteHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Download and add kalpurush.ttf file in your ttf directory, then in the controller...

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
      'default_font_size' => 16,
      'default_font' => 'kalpurush'
       ]);
$stylesheet = '<style>'.file_get_contents('assets/css/style2.css').'</style>';

$html = $this->load->view('print',[],true);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
```